# Need help to find exact match within a small database

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, worksheet-function

In my Excel 2010 database I'm searching for products from several different vendors, but my VLOOKUP function is not retrieving the correct product. For example:

```
Product ID,    Product Name,    Items,    Colors,
123,           apple1,          PC,       white,
**123,         apple2,          Monitor,  silver,**
**123,         apple3,          Speakers, black,**
456,           dell1,           Laptop,   red,
**456,         dell2,           Monitor,  white,**
456,           dell3,           Mouse,    blue,
789,           sony1,           TV,       black,
**789,         sony2,           Speakers, silver,**
789,           sony3,           Headset,  yellow,
```

In the first column there is a drop down menu of `Product ID`. In the second column there is a drop down menu of `Product Name` which populates the third and fourth columns. In these I'm using a VLOOKUP function, which is working perfectly in the third column:

```
=VLOOKUP(B15,$I$15:$K$23,2,FALSE)
```

but not in the fourth:

```
=VLOOKUP(C15,$J$15:$L$23,2,FALSE)
```

When I search for a `Monitor` from `dell2`, it gives me the color "Silver" of monitor from apple and not "White" as I have requested.

How can I search for  the exact match?

Comment: Please provide the actual text of your VLOOKUP call.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(B15,$I$15:$K$23,2,FALSE) this if for the 3rd column

Comment: =VLOOKUP(C15,$J$15:$L$23,2,FALSE) thisis for the 4th column. In any way can I send attachment?

Comment: Via the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/excel-formula/info) here's the docs for VLOOKUP in Excel 2010: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-function-HP010343011.aspx

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/upmfoyf491x202s/test%20for%20Dependent%20drop%20down%20list.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: I posted on dropbox for anyone to take a look at it.

Comment: It's the 3rd example

Comment: Thank you Jesse W at Z, I looked at your link and I have been using these vlookup functions and they work as long as you have no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

It is searching for "Monitor" and returning the first such instance (K16). You should try combining I&J ([CONCATENATE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx)) in your lookup table then searching for B15&C15 there.

If the combined column (with `=I15&J15` copied down) is inserted as ColumnK, then in D15 and copied down to suit:

```
=VLOOKUP(B15&C15,$K$15:$L$23,2,FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you pnuts, but it wouldn't work because the previous cell is always changing.